[UWP]: Combo box collapses when trying to select option first time only
I am using a ComboBox that has 2 options in its dropdown. When user opens the UWP app, the default option is first option in combo box. When user tries to click on combo box to selected option 2, the combo box collapses quickly without allowing user to click on the 2nd option. User needs to click on the combo box again to be able to select the 2nd option.
In addition, sometimes the second option in the combo box will be unable for users to select.
 <ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboBoxOptions, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedOption, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboBoxSelectionChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Foreground="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush }, Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>

In the view Model
public sealed class A
{


    public A
       {
        this.ComboBoxOptions= new ObservableCollection<HelperClass>
        {
            new HelperClass{ Name = "Apples",  IsEnabled = true },
            new HelperClass{ Name = "Bananas", IsEnabled = true },
        };
        this.selectedOption= this.ComboBoxOptions[0]; //Selects first option in dropdown as default
        this.foo();
        }
  
        public ObservableCollection<HelperClass> ComboBoxOptions{ get; set; }

        public HelperClass SelectedOption
        {
           get => this.selectedOption;
           set => this.SetProperty(ref this.selectedOption, value);
        }

       public void ComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.RemovedItems is HelperClass previousOption && previousOption.Name == selectedOption.Name)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (selectedOption.IsEnabled)
        {
           this.SelectedDuration = selectedOption;
        }
        else
        {
           comboBox.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems.FirstOrDefault(); // Select 1st option
        }
      }

        Void foo()
        {
          //Check if option 2 needs to be grayed out.
          (IsGrayedOut)
          {
               this.ComboBoxOptions[1].IsEnabled = false;
          }
          else
          { 
             this.SelectedOption = ComboBoxOptions[0]/ ComboBoxOption[1]; // Based on logic 
          }
         }

    }

I tried handling this problem by removing code for SelectionChanged event and using   

    public HelperClass SelectedOption
    {
         get => this.selectedOption;
         set => this.SetProperty(ref this.selectedOption, value, () => this.Bar());
    }

This helped reduce the collapsing of the combo box but breaks the logic for the case the second option needs to be grayed out. I tried handling the grayout logic in this.Bar() but the option is still selectable. How do I go on about fixing the collapsing of the ComboBox without breaking the logic for grayed out second option?

By default, the ComboBox doesn't show this behavior. The problem should be in your viewmodel, the current code doesn't seem to be enough to help me reproduce your behaviour. Could you please provide a [example] to help us further check the problem for you?

When do you know when a option is "grayed out"? If there are only 2 options; and one can be "disabled", why make the user "choose" in the first place? Why not just 2 buttons. You can disable one without wondering what happens in "selection changed" or what disabling combobox items entails.

@GerrySchmitz Business logic in the backend determines sometimes second option from dropdown is not available to be selected.

The code misses the definition of SetProperty and comboBox, could you please provide a [example] to help us further check the problem for you?
